# Dynamic content not styled in jQuery Mobile ListView with iScroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, iscroll4

I am trying to build a Cordova/PhoneGap app with the option to "Pull Up" to load dynamic content using ajax call. The remote call runs fine and the dynamic content is added as the child elements to  tag. I am using iScroll4 plugin for the "pull" option which works fine.

Initial content in ListView is styled as needed. But it's not styled for the dynamic content.

When I tried the below things. The firstone gives some jquery error.

```
$('#scroller').trigger('pagecreate');
$("#blogList").listview("refresh");
```

I am not able to provide a fiddle, as the question uses phonegap events.

Body Content:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
     <div data-role="content">
         <div id="wrapper">
             <div id="scroller">
                 <ul id="blogList" data-role="listview"></ul>
                 <div id="pullUp">
                     <span class="pullUpIcon"></span><span class="pullUpLabel"></span>
                  </div>
              </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I am using deviceready event insteaed of DOMContentLoaded event as its an PhoneGap app.

JS Code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady() {
            doBootstrap();   // Bootstraps
            getBlogList();   // Initial content loading
            loaded();
        }

        var myScroll, pullUpEl, pullUpOffset, generatedCount = 0;

        function pullUpAction() {
            $("#blogList").append('<li><a href="#">Generated row ' + (++generatedCount) + '</a></li>');
            myScroll.refresh();
        }

        function loaded() {
            pullUpEl = document.getElementById('pullUp');
            pullUpOffset = pullUpEl.offsetHeight;

            myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper', {
                useTransition: true,
                topOffset: pullUpOffset,
                onRefresh: function() {
                    if (pullUpEl.className.match('loading')) {
                        pullUpEl.className = '';
                        pullUpEl.querySelector('.pullUpLabel').innerHTML = 'Pull up to load more...';
                    }
                },
                onScrollMove: function() {
                    if (this.y < (this.maxScrollY - 5) && !pullUpEl.className.match('flip')) {
                        pullUpEl.className = 'flip';
                        pullUpEl.querySelector('.pullUpLabel').innerHTML = 'Release to refresh...';
                        this.maxScrollY = this.maxScrollY;
                    } else if (this.y > (this.maxScrollY + 5) && pullUpEl.className.match('flip')) {
                        pullUpEl.className = '';
                        pullUpEl.querySelector('.pullUpLabel').innerHTML = 'Pull up to load more...';
                        this.maxScrollY = pullUpOffset;
                    }
                },
                onScrollEnd: function() {
                    if (pullUpEl.className.match('flip')) {
                        pullUpEl.className = 'loading';
                        pullUpEl.querySelector('.pullUpLabel').innerHTML = '';
                        pullUpAction();
                    }
                }
            });

            document.getElementById('wrapper').style.left = '0';

        }

        document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }, false);

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        }, false);
    </script>
```

Comment: try using it in document ready because device ready is called after document ready is successfully loaded and so your JQM is not fully loaded.

Comment: In that case, the ListView content will not be there as its loaded only in deviceready event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   $("#blogList").append('<li><a href="#">Generated row ' + (++generatedCount) + '</a></li>');
   $("#blogList").trigger('create');
   $('#blogList').listview('refresh');
```

Comment: Great. It works.. But the "pull up" icont is showing on the top when the page loads and it looks bad.